# PHP read a dat file and output lowest difference

Tags: php, file-get-contents

This is what I have so far:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);

$filename = ('w_data.dat');

$lines = split("\n", file_get_contents($filename));
$spread = array();

for($i = 6; $i < 35; $i++){
    echo $lines[$i];
    $date = $lines[$i][2] . $lines[$i][3];
    $max = $lines[$i][6] . $lines[$i][7];
    $min = $lines[$i][12] . $lines[$i][13];
    $spread[] = $max - $min;
    $lowest = min($spread);

    echo 'date: ', $date, ' max: ', $max, ' min: ', $min, ' lowest: ', $lowest, ' <br>';
}

print_r($lines);
```

I get the output of all 30 days. I only need the line that has the lowest difference.

Thanks for any and all help.

```
    1  88    59    74          53.8       0.00 F       280  9.6 270  17  1.6  93 23 1004.5
    2  79    63    71          46.5       0.00         330  8.7 340  23  3.3  70 28 1004.5
    3  77    55    66          39.6       0.00         350  5.0 350   9  2.8  59 24 1016.8
    4  77    59    68          51.1       0.00         110  9.1 130  12  8.6  62 40 1021.1
    5  90    66    78          68.3       0.00 TFH     220  8.3 260  12  6.9  84 55 1014.4
    6  81    61    71          63.7       0.00 RFH     030  6.2 030  13  9.7  93 60 1012.7
    7  73    57    65          53.0       0.00 RF      050  9.5 050  17  5.3  90 48 1021.8
    8  75    54    65          50.0       0.00 FH      160  4.2 150  10  2.6  93 41 1026.3
    9  86    32*   59       6  61.5       0.00         240  7.6 220  12  6.0  78 46 1018.6
   10  84    64    74          57.5       0.00 F       210  6.6 050   9  3.4  84 40 1019.0
   11  91    59    75          66.3       0.00 H       250  7.1 230  12  2.5  93 45 1012.6
   12  88    73    81          68.7       0.00 RTH     250  8.1 270  21  7.9  94 51 1007.0
   13  70    59    65          55.0       0.00 H       150  3.0 150   8 10.0  83 59 1012.6
   14  61    59    60       5  55.9       0.00 RF      060  6.7 080   9 10.0  93 87 1008.6
   15  64    55    60       5  54.9       0.00 F       040  4.3 200   7  9.6  96 70 1006.1
   16  79    59    69          56.7       0.00 F       250  7.6 240  21  7.8  87 44 1007.0
   17  81    57    69          51.7       0.00 T       260  9.1 270  29* 5.2  90 34 1012.5
   18  82    52    67          52.6       0.00         230  4.0 190  12  5.0  93 34 1021.3
   19  81    61    71          58.9       0.00 H       250  5.2 230  12  5.3  87 44 1028.5
   20  84    57    71          58.9       0.00 FH      150  6.3 160  13  3.6  90 43 1032.5
   21  86    59    73          57.7       0.00 F       240  6.1 250  12  1.0  87 35 1030.7
   22  90    64    77          61.1       0.00 H       250  6.4 230   9  0.2  78 38 1026.4
   23  90    68    79          63.1       0.00 H       240  8.3 230  12  0.2  68 42 1021.3
   24  90    77    84          67.5       0.00 H       350  8.5 010  14  6.9  74 48 1018.2
   25  90    72    81          61.3       0.00         190  4.9 230   9  5.6  81 29 1019.6
   26  97*   64    81          70.4       0.00 H       050  5.1 200  12  4.0 107 45 1014.9
   27  91    72    82          69.7       0.00 RTH     250 12.1 230  17  7.1  90 47 1009.0
   28  84    68    76          65.6       0.00 RTFH    280  7.6 340  16  7.0 100 51 1011.0
   29  88    66    77          59.7       0.00         040  5.4 020   9  5.3  84 33 1020.6
   30  90    45    68          63.6       0.00 H       240  6.0 220  17  4.8 200 41 1022.7
```

Comment: What is in your file?  A `.dat` file is not any standard thing...

Comment: added data for .dat file

Answer (score 1):

```
$veryLowest = null;

for (...) {
    ...

    if ($veryLowest === null || $lowest < $veryLowest) {
        $veryLowest = /* the current line */;
    }
}

echo $veryLowest;
```

Comment: +1 but would benefit from a `foreach` instead of the incremental loop.  BTW, congratulations on passing 100k

Comment: How do I set the first occurrence of the very lowest difference?

Comment: @Smart I don't understand the question. I thought my example demonstrates it?

Comment: I get the last occurrence of the lowest difference.